# I'm having difficulty speeding up my HashMap

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, data-structures, hashmap

I'm given a .txt file with a total of 1 million songs and their respective authors. My given task is to write a HashMap in python which can store this information using either the Author or the Song as a key. I've written a HashMap that works but is running incredibly slow, taking up to 2 minutes to finish. (Expected time is apparently a few seconds at most, according to my tutor)

For collision handling I decided to use linked lists as from what I've gathered it's an effective way to handle collisions without drastically reducing performance.

```
from HashNode import HashNode

class HashTabell:

    def __init__(self, size):
        self.size = size
        self.dict = {}
        self.krock = 0

    def store(self, nyckel, data):
        hashval = self.__hash(nyckel)

        ## Shit is empty
        if self.dict.get(hashval) != None:
            get_val = self.dict[hashval]

            ## Is list, append normally
            if isinstance(get_val, list):
                list2 = self.dict[hashval]
                found = False

                for (k, val) in enumerate(list2):
                    if val.get_nyckel == nyckel:
                        list[k] = HashNode(nyckel, data) ## Update old value
                        found = True
                        break

                if found:
                    self.dict[hashval] = list2
                else:
                    self.dict[hashval] = get_val + [HashNode(nyckel, data)]
                    self.krock += 1
            else:
            ## Create list
                if get_val.get_nyckel() == nyckel:
                    self.dict[hashval] = HashNode(nyckel, data) ## Update old value
                else:
                    self.dict[hashval] = [get_val, HashNode(nyckel, data)] ## Append to existing node
                    self.krock += 1

        else:
            self.dict[hashval] = HashNode(nyckel, data)

    def __getitem__(self, nyckel):
        return search(nyckel)

    def __contains__(self, nyckel):
        return (search(nyckel) != None)

    def search(self, nyckel):
        hashval = self.__hash(nyckel)

        ## Get val
        get_val = self.dict.get(hashval)
        if get_val == None:
            raise KeyError("Key not found")

        ## Check if has multiple entries or not
        if isinstance(get_val, list):
            ## Multiple
            for value in get_val:
                if(get_val.get_nyckel() == nyckel):
                    return get_val
            raise KeyError("Key not found")
        else:
            ## Single
            if get_val.get_nyckel() == nyckel:
                return get_val
            else:
                raise KeyError("Key not found")

    ## Hash function
    def __hash(self, input):
        inp = str(input) ## Get chars
        value = 0

        for k in input:
            value += ord(k)

        return (value % self.size)


    def get_dict(self):
        return self.dict

    def get_krock(self):
        return self.krock
```

Where the HashNode class is simply:

```
class HashNode:
    def __init__(self, nyckel, data):
        self.nyckel = nyckel
        self.data = data

    def get_nyckel(self):
        return self.nyckel

    def get_data(self):
        return self.data
```

I've been staring myself blind with this issue for the past 2 weeks and I'm not getting any help from my lecturer/assistants, would greatly appreciate any advice on how to improve the speed.

Comment: Why do you reimplement your own hashmap on top of dict? Why you do not just use a dict with an object that reimplement the hash function (you can reuse partially existing one by the way). Why do you use `dict` and and `list` as variable names?

Comment: This was a school-assignment where I was meant to do it this way. Variable names just because they made sense at the time (still very new to programming). I managed to figure out that what was causing the slowing was:

1. Using a dict to store key and value pairs over two lists (unsure as to why but I think dict storing worst case is O(n)?)
2. Using linked lists to handle collissions instead of linear probing
3. My hash-function wasn't very good. 

your input helped a bit since it made me question why I was doing it the way I was doing it so thank you.